# K Nearest Neighbour with different distance matrix to each datapoint

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, distance, k-nn

I'm wondering if there is library support in python (such as sklearn) for doing KNN on a data set that has a custom distance matrix (positive definite) for each data point (x is a query point, $x_i$ is a data set point):
$$
d(x,x_i) = (x-x_i)^TQ_i(x-x_i)
$$

I know that for a fixed positive definite matrix for all data points, this is a metric that I can transform into
$$
Q = A^TA
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
d(x,x_i) = (Ax - Ax_i)^T(Ax - Ax_i)
$$
Which I can compute via normal KNN by first transforming the input space via multiplying $A$.

My problem of having a separate matrix for each data point came up because I have a covariance around the neighbourhood of each point. KNN can then be interpreted as what are the most likely neighbourhoods this query point lies in. If a neighbourhood doesn't vary along a dimension then we should penalize difference along that dimension highly in terms of increasing distance.

Comment: You can define custom metrics in sklearn https://stackoverflow.com/q/21052509/58737

Comment: Can Q_i be calculated from x_i?

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte No, that is part of the problem. If so I could use the metric keyword in sklearn. One idea I have is to append the $Q_i$ to $x_i$ and then use a custom metric function to extract each part. The problem is that I don't think this is an actual metric (triangle inequality doesn't make sense here), so k-d trees or ball trees wouldn't necessarily work.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Pratik Deoghare you can create a custom metric on sklearn kNN and you can see how in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052509/sklearn-knn-usage-with-a-user-defined-metric) he provided.

But you want a function to that is different for each $x_i$, that is not a metric in the mathematical sense, but I can see how that could benefit the algorithm either way.

the function you pass as a metric (see how in the link) could be defined as

```py
def creatmydist(AllA):
    Alist = AllA
    def mydist(x, y):
        nonlocal Alist
        if x[-1] == 0: i = y[-1]
        else: i=x[-1]        
        A = Alist[i]
        x = np.dot(A,x[0:len(x)-1])
        y = np.dot(A,y[0:len(y)-1])
        return np.dot(x-y,x-y)
    return mydist
```

Where AllA should be a list with all $A = (A^T)^{-1}Q$ and every $x_i$  should have as last element it's index $i$

Comment: I considered doing this (comment on the original question), but I don't think k-d trees or ball trees would work without a proper metric. I'll give it a test and update when I have some time!